# Sort groups by specific values in two columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to sort the dataset in order of each coloured curve, based on the x-axis value where the y-axis is approximately 0.5. The legend now is based on sequential order. But if you sort the data right, the legend should look like, [item 5, item 1, item 3, item 2, item 4].

```
library(mirt)
dat <- expand.table(LSAT7)
mod <- mirt(dat, 1)
plt <- plot(mod, type = 'trace', facet_items=FALSE) #store the object
print(plt) #plot the object
str(plt) #find the data
plt$panel.args
pltdata <- data.frame(lapply(plt$panel.args, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))[[1]])
pltdata$item <- rep(colnames(dat), each = 50)


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pltdata, aes(x, y, colour = item)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle('ggplot2 Tracelines') + 
  xlab(expression(theta)) + 
  ylab(expression(P(theta))) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to obtain the "x" values associated to the "y" values nearest to 0.5 (using dplyr) and after that, reorder the levels of the "item" variable.

```
library(mirt)
dat <- expand.table(LSAT7)
mod <- mirt(dat, 1)
plt <- plot(mod, type = 'trace', facet_items=FALSE) #store the object
print(plt) #plot the object
str(plt) #find the data
plt$panel.args
pltdata <- data.frame(lapply(plt$panel.args, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))[[1]])
pltdata$item <- rep(colnames(dat), each = 50)

pltdata$item<-as.factor(pltdata$item)
library(dplyr)
aux<-pltdata %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(y-0.5)))

aux<-aux[order(aux$x),]
ord<-as.integer(aux$item)
pltdata$item = factor(pltdata$item,levels(pltdata$item)[ord])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pltdata, aes(x, y, colour = item)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle('ggplot2 Tracelines') + 
  xlab(expression(theta)) + 
  ylab(expression(P(theta))) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5))
```